# Does Flink cache Java classes when running in Cluster (i.e. not via an IDE)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a local flink cluster using

```
./bin/start_local.sh
```

I start a flink job by running

```
./bin/flink run -p 3 lib/myApp.jar <insert command line args here>
```

This works as expected.  However, if I were to update my JAR file (i.e. **lib/myApp.jar**) and restart the job as above, my new JAR does not seem to take effect.  In this particular case, I updated the schema output from the JAR by renaming a field.  The output from the job still had the old field when the job was restarted using the updated JAR.

Is there some cache that needs to get updated?  Is this the correct way of updating an application?   Note that for the purposes here I do not care about Savepoints for now.

Thanks!

Comment: If using maven, have you tried a "mvn clean package"?

Comment: I'm using gradle.   And I did gradle clean first.  Still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because WebUI is still using old jar file. There are two methods after you regenerate your jar file from IDE

**Option # 1:**

Make sure when u generate artifacts, you choose to rebuild option

[image]

then, send the `jar` file again via terminal using the command you used.

`./bin/flink run -p 3 lib/myApp.jar <insert command line args here>`

**Option # 2 :** submit the jar file using [web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8AHs.png)

make sure you have this option enabled in `conf.yaml` file

```
jobmanager.web.submit.enable: true
```

Then submit your jar using option available in UI

[image]

Please let me know if you have any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Some jobs are not stopped when you think they are (for example after ctrl+c), and this can in turn create the illusion of stale JARs when you execute a new *run*. Execution result seems to be unaffected by your most recently packaged code changes!

The best way to prevent this from happening is to **stop all relevant jobs** before re-running your new jar. So do the following:

```
flink list              # lists all job IDs
flink stop <job_id>     # ideally this will work, and no in-flight data is lost
flink cancel <job_id>   # only execute this if previous fails
```

If you now run your new jar everything should work as you expect.
Note that if you have to cancel the job, there is a risk of in-flight data loss; but in some cases it may be the only way (if your event source does not implement *StoppableFunction*)